Why emit event in subscribe() is not emiting the data?
In my child component when I got a success from api call i am emiting data to parent component. But it's not working.
ChildComponent.ts
 taskCompleted(taskId: number) {
    const patchObject: patchDocument = {
      path: 'IsCompleted',
      op: 'replace',
      value: true,
    };
    const patchObjectArray: patchDocument[] = [patchObject];
    this.todoService.completeTask(taskId, patchObjectArray).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.refreshTasks.emit(); //emiting data to parent for refresh
        this.toaster.info('Task Completed');
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.toaster.error(error);
      },
    });
  }

parentComponent.html
<app-task-details-popup (refreshTasks)="refreshTasks()"></app-task-details-popup>

parentComponent.ts
//which is called from emitter
refreshTasks() {
    this.getTasks(); //another api call to get tasks from db
  }
}
 //this method get all todotasks from db
 getTasks() {
    if (this.componentAction == componentActions.Active) {
      this.todoService.getActiveTasks().subscribe({
        next: (activeTasks) => {
          this.tasks = activeTasks;
          this.groupTasksByDate(activeTasks);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          if (error.status === 404) {
            this.tasks = [];
          }
        },
      });
    } else if (this.componentAction === componentActions.Completed) {
      this.todoService.getCompletedTasks().subscribe({
        next: (completedTasks) => {
          this.tasks = completedTasks;
          this.groupTasksByDate(completedTasks);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          if (error.status === 404) {
            this.tasks = [];
          }
        },
      });
    }
  }

The method refreshTasks() is not been called from child also. This are the refrence links
reference Link
reference Link

Please add the code where refreshTasks is initialized.

Do you get a response so in your subscribe your next case runs?

the completeTask which is in child component getting response from db even the toaster is also working good.

@SanjuChilukuri Please share the code for refreshTasks as mentioned in the first comment

Sorry I wasn't 100% clear, I mean the code where the refreshTasks event emitter is initialized. For example if the @Output() decorator were missing, it would be expected behavior.

I added my github link and info about components. once goes through it.

@SanjuChilukuri I got rid of the backend and mocked the APIs, it seems to work fine github repo

@NarenMurali hey bro, what you did you simply remove the my taskCompleted method. but thanks i got a idea to resolve it.

@SanjuChilukuri do post the answer so everyone knows what happened

@NarenMurali what the idea is simply i send two output emitter from child to parent. without any api calls. and i will do api calls in parent. i think it will work.

Great, swapping one problem to another ;)

From the code you've shared it looks like you're correctly emitting the event from the child component. The issue is propably how you're listening for the event in the parent component.
You're listening for the refreshTasks event like this:
<app-task-details-popup (refreshTasks)="refreshTasks()"></app-task-details-popup>

This is correct if refreshTasks is an EventEmitter in the TaskDetailsPopupComponent. However you need to check that refreshTasks is decorated with @Output() in your child component!
That should look something like this:
@Output() refreshTasks = new EventEmitter<void>();

This @Output() decorator is necessary to let Angular know that refreshTasks is a custom event that the TaskDetailsPopupComponent will emit.
If you've already done this and it's still not working than there might be an issue elswhere in your code. hope this helps!

I already tried that approach. still, it is not working..

You didn't set componentAction and you probaly fail both if tests.

Actually, it wont because i am setting component action ngOnInit. but the main thing is the refreshTasks() method in parent not been called.

Well you are subscribing to route.data which may or may not be called and even if, data['status'] does not have to be one of your ACTIONS enum....

Yeah, it is also one of the problem. but, i am emiting data from child component by using event emitter and i am accessing in parent that means the method which i assigned in parent to respective emitter it has to called right. but it's not calling that method.
